# Can't update, can't install from SC 18.04

Tags: updates, software-center, 18.04

I have no idea what is going on, what to check or even where to search for help other than here. The past 5 updates have all frozen at around 75% complete, and I'm trying to install Gnome Calculator and it's stuck at 99%. All other software in the past 2 weeks has failed to install too.

Comment: Updating/installing from the terminal will show error messages that tell what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Ran sudo apt-get update and it went flawlessly, I was then offered a partial upgrade which also went flawlessly and software is now installing. I can't believe it was that simple, I feel so silly. But thanks for helping.